# Preview data form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I need some help, I have a form that before the 'Send' button have a select type 'check' if this is uncheck and the people click on 'send' the form show a pop up with the preview of the all data in the form, if the select is check and the people click on 'send' this is sending normal, but I would like change that, I would like change the select check to a button 'Preview' and when the people click show the pop up with the preview, and the send buttom continue normal send the form.

this is the code for the pop up with the rule if is check or uncheck.

```
    function check_form() {

    var url = "process_estaform.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#estafrm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#dialog").html(data);

               if($("#senditornot").prop("checked") === false ) {
               $("#dialog").attr("title","This dialog box will automatically close.");
               $("#dialog").dialog();
               $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow",function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }).css('display','block');
               }
               else {
            $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").css('display','block');
               }
           },
           error :function() {
               $("#dialog").html(data);
               $("#dialog").attr("title","This dialog box will automatically close.");
               if($("#senditornot").prop("checked") === false ) {
               $("#dialog").dialog();
               $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow",function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }).css('display','block');
               }
               else {
            $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").css('display','block');
               }
           }
         });
    }
```

code html.

```
    <div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sendit" id="senditornot" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
    <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" id="submitter" value="Submit" />

    </div>
    </div>
```

[img form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1vX4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Add following before function check_form.

```
$("#preview").click(function()
{
    var previewData = $("#estafrm").serialize();
    $("#dialog").html(previewData);
})
```

add preview button in code.html

`<input type="button" name="preview" id="preview" value="preview" />`

Added complete code.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function check_form() {

        var url = "process_estaform.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#estafrm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
               $("#dialog").html(data);

               if($("#senditornot").prop("checked") === false ) {
               $("#dialog").attr("title","This dialog box will automatically close.");
               $("#dialog").dialog();
               $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow",function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }).css('display','block');
               }
               else {
            $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").css('display','block');
               }
            },
            error :function() {
               $("#dialog").html(data);
               $("#dialog").attr("title","This dialog box will automatically close.");
               if($("#senditornot").prop("checked") === false ) {
               $("#dialog").dialog();
               $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow",function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }).css('display','block');
               }
               else {
            $("#dialog").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow").css('display','block');
               }
            }
            });
        }

        $("#preview").click(function(){
            var previewData = $("#estafrm").serialize();
            console.log(previewData);
            $("#dialog").html(previewData);
            alert(previewData);
        })
    })

</script>
<body>
    <form name="estafrm" id="estafrm">
     <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  value=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sendit" id="senditornot" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
        <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" id="submitter" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" name="preview" id="preview" value="preview" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy, but I tried to put this before close  }); but doesn't works and I put after, before to close function check_form() but doesn't works. could you help me again please.

Comment: add javascript snippet before check_form

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't works yet. :( I've tried many differents way, but nothing :(

Comment: did you try complete code. put complete code somewhere, you have to debug in browser by putting breakpoints in #preview callback

Comment: I did like you show me in the code, and when I click in preview button, show like prevent advertising and show like this. addressline1=&travaddressline2=&apartnumber=&usctccity=&usstate=&usctcphone=&addresswhile=&addresswhile2=&apartnumberwhile=&usctccitywhile=&usstatewhile=